# undefined references with debgging symbols on android

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk

I am trying to compile my app with debug options set. I have included the android/bitmap.h file. Everything compiles well with methods in android/bitmap.h file, but the linker has problems as it says

```
/home/user5432/workspace/bitmapproj/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/mybitmap.o : In function Java_com_example_plasma_PlasmaView_renderPlasma
"undefined reference to AndroidBitmap_getInfo"
"undefined reference to AndroidBitmap_lockPixels"
"undefined reference to AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels"
```

Can anybody tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Needed to add `LOCAL_LDFLAGS +=-ljnigraphics` in Android.mk file